# pyqt5 Shrinking and Expanding MainWidget while using TableView

Tags: python, pyqt5, resize, model-view

Using pyQt5.

Using QTableView/QAbstractTableModel to display table updates.
When row is added to the table, the MainWindow expands as expected.

When a row is removed, I would like the MainWindow to shrink back. Using ONLY the space that is needed to fit the table.

Below is a simplified example of the problem.
It simply adds 5 rows to the table, and then removes them.

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
   QVBoxLayout

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel) :
   def __init__(self,data=None,parent = None, *args) :
      super(TableModel,self).__init__(parent,*args) 
      
      self.data = data or []
      
   def data(self,index,role) :
      row = index.row()
      col = index.column()
      if role == Qt.DisplayRole and col == 0:
         num = self.data[row]
         return(num)
   
   def rowCount(self,index) :
      return(len(self.data))
   
   def columnCount(self,index) :
      return 1
      

#Only one widget for a main window
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow) :
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) :
      super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
      
      self.data = [] 
      self.counter = 0
      
      #Create the TableView widget that will display the model
      table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
      #Adjusts columns to contents
      table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
        QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
      
      #Expands table if more rows added.
      table.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
         QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
      
      #create a model 
      self.tablemodel = TableModel(self.data)
      #Assign the model to the table
      table.setModel(self.tablemodel)
      
      #Put the table in the main widget's layout
      layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(table,0,Qt.AlignHCenter)
     
      #The actual widget. 
      widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
      widget.setLayout(layout)
      self.widget = widget
      self.setCentralWidget(widget)
      self.show()
      
      ########## 
      self.timer = QTimer()
      self.timer.setInterval(1000)
      self.timer.timeout.connect(self.example)
      self.timer.start()
   
   #example adds 5 rows, and then deletes them.
   def example(self) :
            
      if (self.counter < 5) :
         self.counter += 1
         self.tablemodel.data.append(self.counter)
      elif (self.counter >= 5 and len(self.tablemodel.data) > 0) :
         self.tablemodel.data.pop()      
      self.tablemodel.layoutChanged.emit()
         
  
         
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Issues:

1. When rows are added, the mainwindow expands as expected.
2. When rows are removed, mainwindow does not shrink as expected.

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I've modified my initial question with a "minimal reproducible example"

Answer (score 0):

After much searching found a simplefix. Added a resize function to the MainWindow, that sets the size of the MainWindow to its layout's sizeHint()

Full example below

```
#!/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow, \
   QVBoxLayout

class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel) :
   def __init__(self,data=None,parent = None, *args) :
      super(TableModel,self).__init__(parent,*args) 
      
      self.data = data or []
      
   def data(self,index,role) :
      row = index.row()
      col = index.column()
      if role == Qt.DisplayRole and col == 0:
         num = self.data[row]
         return(num)
   
   def rowCount(self,index) :
      return(len(self.data))
   
   def columnCount(self,index) :
      return 1

#Only one widget for a main window
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow) :
   def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs) :
      super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
      
      self.data = [] 
      self.counter = 0
      
      #Create the TableView widget that will display the model
      table = QtWidgets.QTableView()
      #Adjusts columns to contents
      table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(
        QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
      
      #Expands table if more rows added.
      table.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
         QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
      
      self.table = table
      #create a model 
      self.tablemodel = TableModel(self.data)
      #Assign the model to the table
      table.setModel(self.tablemodel)
      
      #Put the table in the main widget's layout
      layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
      layout.addWidget(table,0,Qt.AlignHCenter)
      self.layout = layout
      #The actual widget. 
      widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
      widget.setLayout(layout)
      self.widget = widget
      self.setCentralWidget(widget)
      self.show()
      
      ########## 
      self.timer = QTimer()
      self.timer.setInterval(1000)
      self.timer.timeout.connect(self.example)
      self.timer.start()
   
   def resize(self) :     
      self.setFixedSize(self.layout.sizeHint())

   #example adds 5 rows, and then deletes them.
   def example(self) :
            
      if (self.counter < 5) :
         self.counter += 1
         self.tablemodel.data.append(self.counter)
      elif (self.counter >= 5 and len(self.tablemodel.data) > 0) :
         self.tablemodel.data.pop()      
      self.tablemodel.layoutChanged.emit()
      self.resize()
         
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```